# Why loading map becomes slowl after I replace ol.source.XYZ's default projection, which is 'EPSG:3587' with 'EPSG:4326‘

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I use openlayers to package BingMaps and other maps. But I found it became slow when loading map after I replace ol.source.XYZ's default projection, which is 'EPSG:3857', with 'EPSG:4326'.

Comment: I assume this is because the tiles need to be reprojected client-side

Comment: @bartvde Thank you , I assume so.